# Got an empty notebook when following the shared link

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ibm-cloud

I'm taking the Data Science course on Coursera, the task is to share your notebook on IBM Watson Studio. I followed all the steps to generate the link but when I try to open it, it shows an empty notebook with one empty cell.

I tried to open on other browsers, private tabs.
Reached out to the staff on Coursera but nothing helpful, only got a screenshot of steps to follow which I did.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save your notebook using "Save Version" menu option and not just "Save"

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you didn't hit the "From URL" tab. Here's a screenshot.

[image]